# remove node if not contain any text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p></p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p></p>
<p>a</p>
```

how to remove those unnecessary tag which don't contain any text? I tried innerHTML but couldn't select them correctly.

Comment: you might need to check whether there are inner nodes also.

Comment: There are quite few methods in jQuery: [Detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), [Empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), [Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply check the tags which are empty and remove them!!

```
 $('p:empty').remove();
```